# OS X Gimp implementation that doesn't use X11

Tags: macos, gimp

I know there are several attempts to bring Gimp to OSX natively, as opposed to its current X11 incarnation. Are any of them usable?

Comment: Since the 2.8.2 version, GIMP runs on OSX natively. No X11 environment is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [gimp-2.6.0 here](http://gimp-app.sourceforge.net/?ref=darwinports.com) and [How to Download and Install on Mac OS X](http://gimp-app.darwinports.com/).
Not sure how stable that is...
Are there any others that work?

Comment: My mac is a powerbook G4, and I don't want to settle for Gimp 2.2. I will settle for Seahorse for now, or just use the MacPorts X11 build of gimp.

Answer (score 2):

I use seashore which is a osx native version of the gimp.
http://seashore.sourceforge.net/

This may work depending on what you need to do. It is based on the gimp but it looks like it doesn't have all of the capabilities.

From the website...
"However, unlike the GIMP, Seashore only aims to serve the basic image editing needs of most computer users, not to provide a replacement for professional image editing products."

I am not a power user so I don't know what it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this version](http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Overview.html) and it seems to work really well on OS X. It still uses X11 but it is a lot less trouble the other ones I've seen.